# (Single line) command to join list of lists, where the inner list are joined by spaces and the outer lists are joined by '\n'

Tags: python, list, join

Is there a way I can join a list of of lists, where the inner list are joined by spaces and the outer lists are joined by '\n'? Is it possible to do this in a single line?

Example input:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

Desired output:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

What I've tried:

```
>>> ' '.join([str(s) for s in [l for l in a]])
'[1, 2, 3] [2, 3, 4]'

>>> ' '.join([str(s) for s in [l.append('\n') for l in a]])
'None None'

>>> a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
>>> [l.append('\n') for l in a]
>>> ' '.join([str(s) for s in [l for l in a]])
"[1, 2, 3, '\\n'] [2, 3, 4, '\\n']"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in a]))
```

This joins the sublists using `'\n'` , and each element in the inner list using `' '` (space) .

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
>>> print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in a]))
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two join functions.

```
'\n'.join(' '.join(str(j) for j in i) for i in a)
```

Example:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(j) for j in i) for i in a))
1 2 3
2 3 4
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
print '\n'.join([' '.join([str(i) for i in b]) for b in a])
```